# My firewall blocks the access to azure database

Tags: azure, firewall

I'm currently doing the Az-900 fundamentals course of Microsoft [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/paths/az-900-describe-cloud-concepts/) and in one of those modules, they give me a sandbox to use azure and learn how to do a database there.

The problem is that the firewall of my work´s pc blocks it, and I can't change it since I do not have any permissions, so I needed to try it in a VM, access to the VM's firewall and create an outbound rule.

But even with that, the firewall still doesn't allow me. I successfully created the rule in the VM's firewall, but still there is something blocking my access to the azure database, what can it be?

I'm a little bad expressing myself in english, so if there are something strange in my question or expressing, please tell me.

I will add captions too if this can help.

This is what I get when trying to [access the created database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLA3E.png)

And this is how I have the firewall rule [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5N4o.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EylHH.png)

Comment: Have you also tried to whitelist your Public IP address at the SQL Server that this database belongs to? See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/secure-database-tutorial

Comment: yes i did added the client ip in the firewall settings of the database, if thats what u mean @KedMardemootoo

Answer (score 0):

Well, this was already solved, i connected the VM through the bridge adapter to the router, with this the vpn and firewall doesnt mess me, so thats all fine thanks to the one who answered to me